# What is the sentence pattern and the grammatical lable for each of the word

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-order

What is the sentence pattern of the below given sentence  and grammatical lable for each of the word .  "Sanskrit is the oldest language." Sanskrit is the subject, 'is' verb ,what can be the grammatical lables given for the rest of the words in the above sentence and what is the sentence pattern.

Answer (score 2):

*Sanskrit is the oldest language.*

The basic clause type is S-P-PC, (subject-predicator-predicative complement) i.e. 'complex intransitive'.

The word classification (part of speech) and function of each word is as follows:

"Sanskrit": noun (noun phrase) functioning as subject.

"Is": verb functioning as predicator.

"The": determinative functioning as determiner.

"Oldest": adjective functioning as modifier (of "language").

"Language": noun functioning as head of the noun phrase "the oldest language", which is predicative complement (PC) of the verb "is".

Answer (score 1):

> Sanskrit is the oldest language.

You have interpreted correctly the subject and the verb (a copula or linking verb).

*language* is the subject complement.  It is modified by the adjective *oldest*.  The noun phrase is fronted by the definite article *the*.

Sentences with linking verbs are commonly of the form [S+V+N](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/link-verbs) as in this case or "S+V+Adj".  This link has a similar example:

> She was a good friend.